# How to group the packages needed to compile a source code

Tags: packages, archiving

I want to give all the needed packages that don't come with a basic LaTeX installation zipped with the source code of a book. But those packages should be in a subdirectory of the directory where the source code is. If someone downloads the `.zip` how can LaTeX use those packages that are neither in the installation directories of LaTeX nor in the same directory as the source code? The goal is to have only the source code in its directory and the packages in a subdirectory. I think the preamble should be something like this:

```
\usepackage{import}
\subimport{packages/metalogo/}{metalogo.sty}
\usepackage{metalogo}
```

But the import package only seems to work with `.tex` files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If TEXINPUTS includes a path component of `.//` then all directories below the current one will be searched.

So (depending on your operating system) you can do

```
TEXINPUTS=.//: pdflatex myfile
```

or set TEXINPUTS with `setenv` or `export` or `set` or whatever is needed. Or for a cross platform solution TEXINPUTS can be set in the `texmf.cnf` configuration file rather than as an environment variable.

Comment: I think this is could be a good solution, I just have to say so in a readme, but if I could make a Makefile to do that it would be even better. Any idea of how would it be?

Comment: @Arturo in a Makefile you just put a tab in front of the line in my answer

Comment: @Arturo or perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23843106/how-to-set-environment-variable-in-makefile

Answer (score 2):

This is taken from the [TeX FAQ](https://texfaq.org) entry [All the files used by this document](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-filesused):

> The [`snapshot` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/snapshot) helps the owner of a LaTeX document obtain a list of the external dependencies of the document, in a form that can be embedded at the top of the document. The intended use of the package is the creation of archival copies of documents, but it has application in document exchange situations too.
>
> The [`bundledoc` system](http://ctan.org/pkg/bundledoc) uses `snapshot` to produce an archive (e.g., `.tar.gz` or `.zip`) of the files needed by your document; it comes with configuration files for use with TeX Live-Unix and MiKTeX. It's plainly useful when you're sending the first copy of a document.
>
> [`mkjobtexmf`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mkjobtexmf) finds which files are used in a 'job', either via the `-recorder` option of TeX, or by using the (Unix) command `strace` to keep an eye on what TeX is doing. The files thus found are copied (or linked) to a directory which may then be saved for transmission or archiving.

You might be interested in `bundledoc`.

Comment: To compile the source the packages should be extracted first in the same directory as the book. I don't want the .sty files to finish in the same directory.