Is there a way to specify directories to search files in them and relative imports in files in these directories
In project folder, I have directory tex from which I would like to import files without specifying directory name. For this, I added this directory to input@path. tex directory actually contains other directories, which contain main.tex files, which I import in entrypoint file. main.tex files should contain relative imports to other files in their directories.
To accomplish this, I tried to use import package, but didn't succeed. MWE:
entrypoint
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{import}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\input@path{{tex}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\import{research}{main}

\end{document}

tex/research/main.tex
Research main

\input{existing/main}

tex/research/existing/main.tex
Existing main


tex paths are always relative to the working directory of the process, not to the file containing the path. there are some packages that try to hide that but ultimately things work smoother if you accept tex syntax is what it is and to dont try to force the behaviour expected from other systems. As long as all your files have unique names (ie not a main.tex in every subdirectory) you don't need any directories at any level; just use \input{main} and call via TEXINPUTS=.//: pdflatex file  and all files in any subdirectory at any level below the current directory will be found.

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/228039/1090
